# How do I make this VBA code more efficient so it does not crash due to lack of memory?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, memory, memory-management

How can I prevent this code from taking up too much memory? Would like to learn for this project and for future reference.

```vb
Sub Part5()

'Updating the classification columns all the way to the right
'Use a long if statement pulling from labels

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim LastRowJira As Integer
    Dim Temp As String
    Dim row_index As String
    Dim x As Integer

 

    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Lastrowpaste = LastRowJira + 1

    LastRowJira = Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("B" & Worksheets("Sheet0").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, AH, AI, AJ, AK, AL, AM, AN, AO As String

    Dim NN As String

    NN = "Non-Nuclear"

    Dim Nuc As String

    Nuc = "Nuclear"

   

    Dim PM As String

    Dim MV As String

   

    PM = "PostMVP"

    MV = "MVP"

   

    Dim SC As String

    Dim WM As String

   

    SC = "GEAM-Supply Chain"

    WM = "GEAM-Work Mgmt"

   

    Dim Conv As String

   

    Conv = "Conversion"

    Lookup = Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("$B$2:$B$" & LastRowJira)

    WholeLookup = Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("$B$2:$GQ$" & LastRowJira)

   

    On Error Resume Next

    For x = 2 To LastRow

       

 

        Temp = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & x).Value

        row_index = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Lookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 1)

       

        AA = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 26)

        AB = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 27)

        AC = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 28)

        AD = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 29)

        AE = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 30)

        AF = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 31)

        AG = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 32)

        AH = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 33)

        AI = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 34)

        AJ = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 35)

        AK = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 36)

        AL = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 37)

        AM = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 38)

        AN = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 39)

        U = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 20)

        Comp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 21)

        Sev = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 198)

        Priority = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WholeLookup, WorksheetFunction.Match(Temp, Lookup, 0), 11)

       

        

        'NN WM (NC S3) MVP , AR 44 -- Where we will paste if true

        If U = "GEAM-Work Mgmt" And (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AR" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AR" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        

        'NN SCM (NC S3) MVP, AS 45

        If U = "GEAM-Supply Chain" And (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AS" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AS" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NN All (NC S3) MVP, AT 46

        If (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AT" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AT" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NN WM (NC S3), AU 47

        If U = "GEAM-Work Mgmt" And (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AU" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AU" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NN SCM (NC S3), AV 48

        If U = SC And (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AV" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AV" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

        'NN All (NC S3) All, AW 49

        If (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AW" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AW" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NUC WM (NC S3) MVP, AX 50

        If U = WM And (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (AA = Nuc Or AB = Nuc Or AC = Nuc Or AD = Nuc Or AE = Nuc Or AF = Nuc Or AG = Nuc Or AH = Nuc Or AI = Nuc Or AJ = Nuc Or AK = Nuc Or AL = Nuc Or AM = Nuc Or AN = Nuc Or AO = Nuc) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AX" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AX" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NUC SCM (NC S3) MVP, AY 51

        If U = SC And (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (AA = Nuc Or AB = Nuc Or AC = Nuc Or AD = Nuc Or AE = Nuc Or AF = Nuc Or AG = Nuc Or AH = Nuc Or AI = Nuc Or AJ = Nuc Or AK = Nuc Or AL = Nuc Or AM = Nuc Or AN = Nuc Or AO = Nuc) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AY" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AY" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NUC All (NC S3) MVP, AZ 52

        If (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (AA = Nuc Or AB = Nuc Or AC = Nuc Or AD = Nuc Or AE = Nuc Or AF = Nuc Or AG = Nuc Or AH = Nuc Or AI = Nuc Or AJ = Nuc Or AK = Nuc Or AL = Nuc Or AM = Nuc Or AN = Nuc Or AO = Nuc) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AZ" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AZ" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NUC WM (NC S3), BA 53

        If U = WM And (AA = Nuc Or AB = Nuc Or AC = Nuc Or AD = Nuc Or AE = Nuc Or AF = Nuc Or AG = Nuc Or AH = Nuc Or AI = Nuc Or AJ = Nuc Or AK = Nuc Or AL = Nuc Or AM = Nuc Or AN = Nuc Or AO = Nuc) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BA" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BA" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NUC SCM (NC S3), BB 54

        If U = SC And (AA = Nuc Or AB = Nuc Or AC = Nuc Or AD = Nuc Or AE = Nuc Or AF = Nuc Or AG = Nuc Or AH = Nuc Or AI = Nuc Or AJ = Nuc Or AK = Nuc Or AL = Nuc Or AM = Nuc Or AN = Nuc Or AO = Nuc) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BB" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BB" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NUC All (NC S3), BC 55

        If (AA = Nuc Or AB = Nuc Or AC = Nuc Or AD = Nuc Or AE = Nuc Or AF = Nuc Or AG = Nuc Or AH = Nuc Or AI = Nuc Or AJ = Nuc Or AK = Nuc Or AL = Nuc Or AM = Nuc Or AN = Nuc Or AO = Nuc) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BC" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BC" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'MVP S3, BD 56

        If (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BD" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BD" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'PostMVP S3, BE 57

        If (AA = PM Or AB = PM Or AC = PM Or AD = PM Or AE = PM Or AF = PM Or AG = PM Or AH = PM Or AI = PM Or AJ = PM Or AK = PM Or AL = PM Or AM = PM Or AN = PM Or AO = PM) And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BE" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BE" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NN Conv WM S3 MVP, BF 58

        If U = WM And (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And Comp = Conv And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BF" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BF" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NN Conv SCM S3 MVP, BG 59

        If U = SC And (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And Comp = Conv And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BG" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BG" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NN Conv All S3 MVP, BH 60

        If (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And Comp = Conv And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BH" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BH" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NN Conv WM S3, BI 61

        If U = WM And (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And Comp = Conv And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BI" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BI" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NN Conv SCM S3, BJ 62

        If U = SC And (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And Comp = Conv And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BJ" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BJ" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'NN Conv All S3, BL 63

        If (AA = NN Or AB = NN Or AC = NN Or AD = NN Or AE = NN Or AF = NN Or AG = NN Or AH = NN Or AI = NN Or AJ = NN Or AK = NN Or AL = NN Or AM = NN Or AN = NN Or AO = NN) And Comp = Conv And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BL" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BL" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'Nuc Conv SCM S3 MVP, BM 64

        If U = SC And (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (AA = Nuc Or AB = Nuc Or AC = Nuc Or AD = Nuc Or AE = Nuc Or AF = Nuc Or AG = Nuc Or AH = Nuc Or AI = Nuc Or AJ = Nuc Or AK = Nuc Or AL = Nuc Or AM = Nuc Or AN = Nuc Or AO = Nuc) And Comp = Conv And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BM" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BM" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'Nuc Conv All S3 MVP, BN 65

        If (AA = "MVP" Or AB = "MVP" Or AC = "MVP" Or AD = "MVP" Or AE = "MVP" Or AF = "MVP" Or AG = "MVP" Or AH = "MVP" Or AI = "MVP" Or AJ = "MVP" Or AK = "MVP" Or AL = "MVP" Or AM = "MVP" Or AN = "MVP" Or AO = "MVP") And (AA = Nuc Or AB = Nuc Or AC = Nuc Or AD = Nuc Or AE = Nuc Or AF = Nuc Or AG = Nuc Or AH = Nuc Or AI = Nuc Or AJ = Nuc Or AK = Nuc Or AL = Nuc Or AM = Nuc Or AN = Nuc Or AO = Nuc) And Comp = Conv And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

           Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BN" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BN" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'Nuc Conv WM S3, BO 66

        If U = WM And (AA = Nuc Or AB = Nuc Or AC = Nuc Or AD = Nuc Or AE = Nuc Or AF = Nuc Or AG = Nuc Or AH = Nuc Or AI = Nuc Or AJ = Nuc Or AK = Nuc Or AL = Nuc Or AM = Nuc Or AN = Nuc Or AO = Nuc) And Comp = Conv And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BO" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BO" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'Nuc Conv SCM S3, BP 67

        If U = SC And (AA = Nuc Or AB = Nuc Or AC = Nuc Or AD = Nuc Or AE = Nuc Or AF = Nuc Or AG = Nuc Or AH = Nuc Or AI = Nuc Or AJ = Nuc Or AK = Nuc Or AL = Nuc Or AM = Nuc Or AN = Nuc Or AO = Nuc) And Comp = Conv And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BP" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BP" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

       

        'Nuc Conv All S3, BQ 68

        If (AA = Nuc Or AB = Nuc Or AC = Nuc Or AD = Nuc Or AE = Nuc Or AF = Nuc Or AG = Nuc Or AH = Nuc Or AI = Nuc Or AJ = Nuc Or AK = Nuc Or AL = Nuc Or AM = Nuc Or AN = Nuc Or AO = Nuc) And Comp = Conv And (Sev = "SEV 2" Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "High") Or (Sev = "SEV 3" And Priority = "Highest")) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BQ" & x).Value = row_index

        Else

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BQ" & x).Value = vbNullString

        End If

              

    Next x
End Sub
```

I was considering a nested for loop? I tried separating loops for each column? I am a novice if you could not tell by the code.

Comment: You don't really describe the intent of your code, and I only skimmed it. But I'm curious if this is something you could just do with formulas (`IF()`, etc.) instead of resorting to VBA to compare values in columns. I suspect formulas could do most of the heavy lifting.

Comment: The intent is to automate uploading a Jira export and transforming the data. It is a task I have been doing 4 times a day because we don’t have access to certain Jira dashboards and I want people on my team to be able to do it with just the click of a button. Would using the if formula in VBA and auto filling down, rather than using if statements, use less memory?

Comment: FYI with that `On Error Resume Next` you will never know if it's working correctly or not...

Comment: There is no logic for condition `Nuc Conv WM S3 MVP`, is that correct. Also `AO` used in the logic is not assigned a value.

Comment: I think there is logic for Nuc Conv WM S3 MVP? Or maybe I am missing something. Just fixed the AO problem in my code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I will guess*: If the issue is memory then instead of creating arrays for `Lookup` and `WholeLookup`, try using the Range.

Replace this:

```
Lookup = Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("$B$2:$B$" & LastRowJira)
WholeLookup = Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("$B$2:$GQ$" & LastRowJira)
```

With this:

```
Set Lookup = Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("$B$2:$B$" & LastRowJira)
Set WholeLookup = Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("$B$2:$GQ$" & LastRowJira)
```

Comment: This worked instantly. Why is that?

Comment: It's probably more efficient to use the data in the worksheet itself rather than traverse your arrays. I'm guessing, but maybe there's indexing going on in the worksheet that we don't know about.